# SSRS Excel Export adds total rows for groups, not other formats

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, export-to-excel

I have a report with 3 groups. Each group is a child of the one before it.  The two child groups are hidden by default and have their visibility toggled by clicking its parent.  Columns to the right contain aggregate values for each of the groups.

My problem is when i try to export the report to Excel there is a row added for each parent group.  Viewing on the web or exporting to PDF don't have this problem.

Anyone have an idea for how to prevent this row from displaying?

This is how it looks on the web or PDF (how I want it to look):

[image: This is how it looks on the web/PDF]

This is how it looks when exported to Excel (do not want):
 [image: This is how it looks in Excel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was (allegedly) fixed by Microsoft back in 2010 (I know - it sounds unbelievable). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2462084

But according to this **Microsoft Answer**, it's a known "feature"

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b927902-f3d8-46b9-acd0-fd22843b980f/
"When exporting to Microsoft EXCEL, excel **will add an extra row** for each group"

I found one solution that shouldn't work but might (I haven't tested it):

**Insert Column -> Outside Group - Left** of your Level 2 Group
go to the newly created Static members (**Column Groups/Advanced Mode**), and set the **Hidden** Property to **True** 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1f221636-cd84-4d89-a226-fba6a4d660d1/

Comment: thanks.  I added a header row for each group and it formatted a little better, but still not a great solution.

Comment: I've found and installed that update and it still shows extra rows in Excel.

Comment: The workaround worked for me, but you should've mentioned that OP needs to add invisible **rows**, not **columns**, since Excel shows extra rows for him, not columns (in contrast to the linked technet forum post).

Comment: "excel will add an extra row" full of arbitrary nonsense that the report designer did not request. great, thanks, MS.

Comment: Yes this works. The way I did it was right click on the Group and select "Add Total" > After Group. deploy the report and confirm that the same extra total now shows in web and export. Then use advanced mode to hide the first static row of the total group.